# How to switch the android wired network?

Tags: java, android

Need to turn on the wired network using below code, but An exception occurs.

```
mEthManager = (EthernetManager) 
mContext.getSystemService(Context.ETHERNET_SERVICE); 
mEthManager.setEthernetEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add permission in AndroidMainfest.xml

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```